# Applied crossword solving

Tags: crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**6** It's applied to the Down answers
**9** An expression of mild surprise
**11** Gas station fixture
**12** Measure of file size
**13** Eastman invention
**14** A Kansan woman
**16** Not bespoke

#### Down

**1** It's applied to the Across answers
**2** Mystery on high
**3** Like a racetrack
**4** La sequel
**5** A wizard's home
**6** Part of a pangram
**7** Fro counterpart
**8** 15D's home
**10** Launder
**12** Central Perk, e.g.
**14** *A Wrinkle in Time* character
**15** An eponymous Lopez
**16** Hi
**17** A computer company started in 1939

Comment: My first crossword, so have mercy.  `:-)` Seriously, I'd appreciate any feedback (perhaps [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) would be best).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The crossword's solution:

> [image]

What's going on here:

> 1-Across and 6-Down say that something's being applied to all of the answers. It turns out that those are ROT THIRTEEN and ATBASH: each answer is encoded before entry using one of those two codes (depending on whether it is Across or Down).
>
>  Luckily, these codes are self-inverses, so if you have a letter in an Across clue, you can Atbash and then rot13 it to see what the Down clue's letter should be. And vice versa: if you have the Down letter, you can get the Across letter.
>
>  The Across and Down clue answers are shown here:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Not sure what's up with 14-down -- maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The _Wrinkle_ character is IT. Dangit, did I mess up?…